# Get the product category name and description in Woocommerce Single Product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I've been using the WooCommerce Codex, but I can't seem to get the data to display. I simply want to display the product category and descriptions to display on single product pages for my own custom layout like so.

```
<?php global $product; echo $product->get_attributes; ?>

<?php global $product; echo $product->get_short_description; ?>
```

Comment: You can display these information using default woocommerce widgets or shortcodes. My be this link help you. https://atlantisthemes.com/woocommerce-categories/

Comment: If you think that's true you've misunderstood what I'm after. I already tried all of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can have many product categories for a product, you will need to use a foreach loop. The `$term` variable is the `WP_Term` object…

```
<?php 
    foreach( wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat' ) as $term ){
        if( $term ){
            echo $term->name . '<br>'; // product category name
            if ($term->description)
                echo $term->description . '<br>'; // Product category description
        }
    }
?>
```

Tested and works

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in your `function.php` file of your current theme

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function() {
    global $product;
    echo $product->list_attributes();
}, 25);
```

Next Use below code where you want product attributes to display

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) 
{
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
} 
$has_row    = false;
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
ob_start();
```

just `print_r($attributes)` so you can get all attributes of specific product then just get attributes which you want to display.that's it

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the other answer was more what I was after. For future reference I highly recommend against suggestions to edit functions.php directly, using Code Snippets is a much more practical and safer way of adding additional functionality https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/ Besides I'm using a new development platform where editing the functions.php file would have zero effect anyway :)